# impl Default sugar for large struct without derive

Tags: rust, syntactic-sugar

If I have a struct I need `Default` implemented on, if all the field's types have `Default` implemented themsevles, then I can use the `derive` macro, otherwise I need to implement `Default` manually. However, there are some situations where I have a large struct where almost all the fields would be derivable, except there is a small number of fields with types which do not have `Default` implemented, and I can `impl` myself because the type is external. This ends up with the situation in the below example. I would prefer to avoid this as it means I need to keep the fields in sync between two places, which is more time consuming, error prone, and verbose. I'm hoping there might be some syntactical suagr to avoid this, but I'm new to rust and can't think of any. I'm thinking something like:

```rust
impl Default for Data2 {
    fn default() -> Self {
        Self {
            external_data: ExternalType::One,
            ..Default::default(),
        }
    }
}
```

Example

```rust
#[derive(Default)]
struct Data {
    name: Option<String>,
    flag: bool,
    selected: Vec<String>,
    show_reference: Option<String>,
    index: Option<usize>,
    create_name: String,
    create_type: String,
}

enum ExternalType {
    One,
    Two,
}
// #[derive(Default)]
struct Data2 {
    name: Option<String>,
    flag: bool,
    selected: Vec<String>,
    show_reference: Option<String>,
    index: Option<usize>,
    create_name: String,
    create_type: String,
    external_data: ExternalType,
}
impl Default for Data2 {
    fn default() -> Self {
        Self {
            name: Default::default(),
            flag: Default::default(),
            selected: Default::default(),
            show_reference: Default::default(),
            index: Default::default(),
            create_name: Default::default(),
            create_type: Default::default(),
            external_data: ExternalType::One,
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The *derivative* crate supports customising the `Default` derivation. I don't know if it works with non-Default sub-types though, you'll have to check.

Comment: Fork ExternalType's crate and implement Default for it? Also submit a patch upstream.

Comment: @hkBst that works if there is a reasonable default for all use cases. But sometimes Default is not implemented because there is no sensible default in general, but there is in certain contexts for users.

Comment: @Max888, good point, had not thought of that.

Answer (score 5):

I think the [`smart-default`](https://docs.rs/smart-default/latest/smart_default/derive.SmartDefault.html) crate can handle this. It lets you derive `SmartDefault`, which derives `Default` for all fields except those with a `#[default(my_default_value)]` attribute.

Example:

```rust
use smart_default::SmartDefault;

#[derive(SmartDefault)]
enum Foo {
    Bar,
    #[default]
    Baz {
        #[default = 12]
        a: i32,
        b: i32,
        #[default(Some(Default::default()))]
        c: Option<i32>,
        #[default(_code = "vec![1, 2, 3]")]
        d: Vec<u32>,
        #[default = "four"]
        e: String,
    },
    Qux(i32),
}
```

There's also the more general [`derivative`](https://mcarton.github.io/rust-derivative/latest/Default.html) crate which lets you customize how *all* derives work, not just `Default`, but is a tad more verbose (because it's more general).

Example:

```rust
use derivative::Derivative;

#[derive(Derivative)]
#[derivative(Default)]
pub struct RegexOptions {
    pub pats: Vec<String>,
    #[derivative(Default(value="10 * (1 << 20)"))]
    pub size_limit: usize,
    #[derivative(Default(value="2 * (1 << 20)"))]
    pub dfa_size_limit: usize,
    pub case_insensitive: bool,
    pub multi_line: bool,
    pub dot_matches_new_line: bool,
    pub swap_greed: bool,
    pub ignore_whitespace: bool,
    #[derivative(Default(value="true"))]
    pub unicode: bool,
}
```

Comment: “but is a tad more verbose (because it's more general)” it's also because when I created derivative, things like `#[default = 12]` weren't possible yet. I could simplify the syntax a bit nowadays, but I prefer the consistency.

Comment: @mcarton Not a criticism at all. I actually like the consistency of `derivative`, and I'll never fault someone who actually produces a valuable crate (which is more than I can say for myself).

Answer (score 4):

As with most Orphan rule problems the only option available is the New Type pattern but I'm not sure this is really an improvement over a manual default impl.

```rust
struct ExternalWithDefault(ExternalType);

impl Default for ExternalWithDefault {
  fn default() -> Self {
    Self(ExternalType::One)
  }
}

...

#[derive(Default)]
struct Data2 {
    name: Option<String>,
    flag: bool,
    selected: Vec<String>,
    show_reference: Option<String>,
    index: Option<usize>,
    create_name: String,
    create_type: String,
    external_data: ExternalWithDefault,
}
```

Comment: This isn't the _only_ option, but it's still a good option (and was what I was going to suggest).